# Is C\C++ built dll runs real-time in LabView

Tags: c#, c++, c, labview

I would like to use C\C++ generated DLLs in LabView, like [this example](http://www.ni.com/example/2719/en/) or [this one](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019Ls1SAE&l=en-CA).
I am wondering if it deploys and runs the code on my target machine (my PXIe) or the DLL runs on the computer which is running LabView.
National instruments, in its [using external codes in LabView](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/370109b.pdf) page 15 under Characteristics of the Two Calling Approaches, mention that,

> 1. You compile the source code and link it to form executable code. If you
>      already have a compiled DLL, this step is not necessary.
> 2. LabVIEW calls the executable code when the Call Library Function
>      Node or CIN executes.
> 3. LabVIEW passes input data from the block diagram to the executable
>      code.
> 4. LabVIEW returns data from the executable code to the block diagram.

Which I believe it does not clarify whether or not the DLL runs on the target device, aka real-time.
Moreover, I found [this document](https://www.ni.com/en-ca/innovations/white-papers/13/c-c---embedded-system-design-tools.html) which was quite confusing since it did not refer to any specific method directly.

Side note: I need to run C/C++ code on PXIe and I need to call it from my LabVIEW code real-time.

Comment: Would you describe your configuration a little more? It sounds like you have two systems (PXIe and LabVIEW RT) -- what OS does the PXIe use? what hardware does LVRT have? how are they connected?

Answer (score 2):

I have never done this, so I can only try to give a few hints which might help:

- If you want to use a dll, it must run on the target where your LabVIEW application runs: If your application runs on a desktop computer, the dll is accessed on the desktop computer. If your application runs on the PXI, the dll must run on the PXI.
- Have a look at [this NI website](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019M0tSAE):

  > If the shared library is C++-based, National Instruments strongly
  >   recommends using the MSVC 2009 or MSVC 2010 compilers.

  and

  > If your DLL works on a Windows machine, it may work in LabVIEW
  >   Real-Time (NI PharLap ETS). However, the code will fail if it calls
  >   functions that are not included in the Real-Time operating system's
  >   subset of Win32.

  On this website they also have a tool which checks whether a specific dll will work.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, answering the question.
I was mostly wondering about the "call library function node" block in LabView.
Even though it was not the answer I was looking for, it was quite helpful.